# Take the index of a variable in Maple.

Tags: math-software, maple

Are there some functions in Maple which can take the index of a variable. For example, we define are there some functions f in Maple such that f(x[2,3]) = [2,3]? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f:= x-> `if`(x::indexed, [op(x)], [][]);
```